# MongoDB: Nested $and not working

Tags: mongodb

### Problem

Let's say we have three documents:

```
[
  {
    row: [
      {identifier: 'a', value: 10},
      {identifier: 'b', value: 24},
      {identifier: 'c', value: 3},
    ]
  },
  {
    row: [
      {identifier: 'a', value: 11},
      {identifier: 'b', value: 75},
      {identifier: 'c', value: 4},
    ]
  },
  {
    row: [
      {identifier: 'a', value: 2},
      {identifier: 'b', value: 1},
      {identifier: 'c', value: 3},
    ]
  }
]
```

### Expected result

Every row's value should be `null` if any condition is not met. The condition must include the `identifier`. That is the problem for me.

```
[
  {
    row: [
      {identifier: 'a', value: null}, // Because it's 'a' and lower than 10
      {identifier: 'b', value: null}, // Because 'a' is lower than 10
      {identifier: 'c', value: null}  // Because 'a' is lower than 10
    ]
  },
  {
    row: [
      {identifier: 'a', value: 11}, // Because it's 'a' and not lower than 10
      {identifier: 'b', value: 75}, // Because 'a' or 'c' are not lower than 10, greater than 5
      {identifier: 'c', value: 4}   // Because it's 'c' and greater than 5
    ]
  }, 
  {
    row: [
      {identifier: 'a', value: null}, // Because it's 'a' and lower than 10
      {identifier: 'b', value: null}, // Because 'a' is lower than 10
      {identifier: 'c', value: null}  // Because 'a' is lower than 10
    ]
  }
]
```

### Approach #1

```
// ... Rest
$project: {
  row: {
    $cond: [
      {
        $eq: [
          {
            $size: {
              $filter: {
                input: '$row',
                as: 'row',
                cond: {
                  $and: [ // Using $or here produces an output
                    {
                      $and: [
                        {$eq: ['$$row.identifier', 'a']},
                        {$gt: ['$$row.value', 10]}
                      ],
                    },
                    {
                      $and: [
                        {$eq: ['$$row.identifier', 'b']},
                        {$lt: ['$$row.value', 5]}
                      ]
                    }  
                 ]
              }
            }
          },
          0
        ]
      },
      {
        $map: {
          input: '$row',
          as: 'row',
          in: {identifier: '$$row.identifier', value: null}
        }
      },
      '$row'
    ]
  }
}
// ... Rest
```

I thought MongoDB sees this:

```
(A AND B) AND (C AND D)
```

And it evaluates the brackets first, but that's not the case.

### Approach #2

When I substitute it with `$nor` MongoDB throws:

> MongoError: Unrecognized expression '$nor'

The query as a whole works fine when I change the first `$and` to `$or` but it's not the result I expect.

---

### Update

One condition is working fine:

```
$eq: [
  {
    $size: {
      $filter: {
        input: '$row',
        as: 'row',
        cond: {
          $or: [
            {
              $and: [
                {$eq: ['$$row.identifier', 'a']},
                {$gt: ['$$row.value', 10]}
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  0
]
```

Now all row's values become `null`. If I add a second condition it get's inverted (`$gt` becomes `$lt`). I don't see why.

Comment: What's the expected result here ?

Comment: It's part of a bigger query. I added the expected result.

Comment: `(A AND B) AND (C AND D)` should work as expected. What is not working ? Can you add input documents & query criteria corresponding expected output ?

Comment: @Veeram it's strange. When I substitute the top-level `$and` with or I get a result. With `$and` I get nothing! I'm gonna add a set of example documents.

Comment: @Veeram I extended approach #1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need below criteria for the expected output. You are also missing [`$$`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/) reference which is used to reference the user variable created in `as` in filter operator.

```
{
  "$or":[
    {"$and":[
      {"$eq":["$$row.identifier","a"]},{"$lte":["$$row.value",10]}
    ]},
    {"$and":[
      {"$eq":["$$row.identifier","b"]},{"$lt":["$$row.value",5]}
    ]}
  ]
}
```

Comment: I missed them only in the example not my actual code.

Comment: So I just noticed in the updated query you are using $eq with size not $gt. Is that intentional ? That may be your problem. Nested `$and` will evaluate all the conditions mentioned in $and which it is doing. So size will be 0 for all the rows for the query criteria you have posted and $eq will evaluate the if block which is to set all the rows to null for all documents.

Comment: No, something that worked during the whole days work ;) I was able to specify the problem even more and it's strange: When I use `$lt` instead of `$gt` it works as expected. But I can't get to work both at the same time. One of the conditions is always inverted. Must be a logical error.

Comment: So when you use `{"$gt":["$$row.value",10]}` & `$eq` condition for `$size` what output do you get ? All rows in all documents set to null ?

Comment: When I use only one condition it's working fine. Any second condition get's inverted (`$gt` becomes `$lt`).

Comment: Sorry I meant  your nested `$and` criteria from post i.e. `{
  "$and":[
    {"$and":[
      {"$eq":["$$row.identifier","a"]},{"$gt":["$$row.value",10]}
    ]},
    {"$and":[
      {"$eq":["$$row.identifier","b"]},{"$lt":["$$row.value",5]}
    ]}
  ]
}` &  `$eq` condition for `$size`. What output do you get ?

Comment: Please see the Update at my question.

Comment: Well, I finally figured it out. That wouldn't be possible without your great support! Thank you so much for this, you helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$addFields` to create temporary field which will represent whether current document matches all conditions using ([$allElementsTrue](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/allElementsTrue/)) and then [$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) to generate expected output

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            matches: {
                $allElementsTrue: {
                    $map: {
                        input: "$row",
                        as: "r",
                        in: {
                           $switch: {
                              branches: [
                                 { case: { $and: [{$eq: ["$$r.identifier", "a"]},{$lte: ["$$r.value", 10] }] }, 
                                     then: false },
                                 { case: { $and: [{$eq: ["$$r.identifier", "b"]},{$gte: ["$$r.value", 5] }] }, 
                                     then: false },
                              ],
                              default: true
                           }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            row: {
                $map: {
                    input: "$row",
                    as: "r",
                    in: {
                         $cond: { 
                            if: { $eq: [ "$matches", true ] }, 
                            then: "$$r", 
                            else: { identifier: "$$r.identifier", value: null } 
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: I guess your solution only set's the values to `null` where the condition is met. What I need is that all values should be null if any of the conditions is met.

Comment: @Julian try now, you have to use $switch with $map to compare each single item of your array, otherwise value < 5 will be checked for all items in your array